# On/Off login button

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

I have a JLabel set up as a button which runs the login logic for my application.

If user input is not valid, a JOptionPane pop-up displays a "Invalid Credentials" message and nothing else happens.

If login is successful, the button changes color (new ImageIcon), the username and password fields are cleared and the system calls the panel associated with the user's profile (CardLayout).

Once the user is logged in, I want to be able to click the same JLabel and logout of the system. The icon changes back to it's original state (first ImageIcon) and all cards are removed.

I am close to getting this behavior, but when I click to logout I also get the "Invalid Credentials" message.  How can I execute the logout logic and stop the system from running the login logic again? I have tried a jToggleButton instead, but I get the same behavior.

Here is part of my code:

```
  if (userAccount == null) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Credentials!");

  } else{

       CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) container.getLayout();
       container.add("workArea",    userAccount.getRole().createWorkArea(container, userAccount,inOrganization, inEnterprise, system));
       layout.next(container);
       ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("loginBlue.jpg"));
       loginButton.setIcon(img);
       userNameJTextField.setText("");
       passwordField.setText("");

       loginButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
       public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
       loginButton.setIcon(image);
       container.removeAll();

       }
       });
  }
```

Comment: Post an [SCCEE](http://sccee.org) for faster help. It will be easier for us to SEE what you are talking about, and try and find a solution.

Comment: Don't use a JLabel as a button. Use a JButton. JButton can have an icon too, and reacts like a button: it can be clicked with the mouse **and** the keyboard. The click can be "escaped" by leaving the button's area, etc. All things that a JLabel doesn't provide, because a JLabel is not a button.